# Web Part Date Column Expiry

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have an out--of-the-box Web Part which displays job flyer PDFs. I recently had to re-create a date column but the expiry functionality no longer works. Prior to this a job flyer would no longer appear after the expiry date.

Can anyone clue me in on how to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to adjust the view/filter on the web part to account for your recreated column and the PDFs will disappear.

Site Actions, Edit page. Click the down arrow on your web part and select Modify Web Part. Click the link/button to Edit the View.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Edited response.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try (can never find that link)...

Comment: For the filter it says "show the items when" column [Closing Date] "is less than"... but I don't know what to enter in the text box after this?

Comment: Change the column to the appropriate date column and enter as typed, [Today]

Comment: There are some jobs with no closing dates and when I do this, they do not show. Weird thing is that this was working all along...

Comment: Then add an additional option Or [your column] is equal to (leave the box blank) and you should be good to go.